# Dynamic APIs with Firebase

Tags: api, firebase

How does Firebase create those dynamically updating datasets?
https://www.firebase.com/docs/open-data/

I am trying to use Kimono to create an API but so far the only way I know how to export the data to Firebase is to import the JSON from Kimono but I need something that automatically updates Firebase if there are changes.

Comment: Firebase has a well-documented, public API that you can use to update data: https://www.firebase.com/docs/. So when something changes in your dataset, you update the corresponding data in Firebase, which in turn notifies all clients. The open data sets are just specialized Firebases that are available for everyone to read.

Comment: If you have a suggestion for an open data set that you think would be popular and useful, feel free to contact us at support at firebase. We're happy to hear ideas. Frank's answer is authoritative regarding how you would create your own public data.

Comment: There isn't a specific data set that I have in mind but I was more interested in the code behind it like what is keeping it up to date. Sorry if the question seems a bit off, I'm still a newbie at it.